# AXIS2 webservice client java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: tomcat, apache-axis

I'm creating a client using axis2 to consume a third party ws, everything **works fine in the tomcat server in my machine**, but once deployed to the server I'm not able to run it.

I have already checked:

- Third party URL is up and running

  No firewalls in the server

  Tomcat reports AXIS2 is working correctly (checking the AXIS2 happy page)

```
[INFO] Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://third.party.URL]
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked whether the server can access the third party URL (with wget or curl or something like that)?

Comment: Yes, by the time we had the issue we were able to reach the third-party url by curl... that was all the axis2 client options.

Answer (score 6):

FOUND IT!
actually is not something about the Tomcat server but the AXIS2 Client configuration, by this post http://wso2.org/forum/thread/1878

You might need to set the HEADER_PROTOCOL_10 in the stub properties.

```
Options options=stub._getServiceClient().getOptions();
options.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HTTP_PROTOCOL_VERSION,org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_10);
```

Now works!!!